# Como utilizar o fullscreenchange no React?

Tags: javascript, react

Tenho a necessidade de executar uma ação, quando o usuário sai do modo de tela cheia do navegador (pressionando <kbd>ESC</kbd>).
Já verifiquei que o evento chamado é o `fullscreenchange` porém não consegui faze-lo funcionar no React.

Estou utilizando Functional Components.
Segue minha implementação

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (videoElement) {
      document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', action, false);
      document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', action, false);
      document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', action, false);
      document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', action, false);
    }
}, [videoElement]);
```

Comment: se está verificando a mudança `videoElement`, e se é verdade você adiciona os eventos, será que esses eventos não teriam que ser carregandos na criação do componente?

Comment: Pois então. Adicionei um outro listener dentro desta condição.
`document.addEventListener("keydown", getKeyBoardInteration, false);`  esse listening está funcionando corretamente, porém os de `fullscreenchange` não.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O elemento que deve receber o listening é o elemento que recebeu o `requestFullScreen`, que no caso não é o `document`, mas sim um elemento específico.

Adicionando o listening na referência do elemento tudo funciona corretamente.